# How to add additional GET parameters in a mixed Form/HREF link that uses a modal box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue that is a little tricky.

First, for folks who will run my snippet first -- when you run my example and click `Generate`, you will first see a modal box, which (on my backend) first reads the `$_GET` data.  My submit mechanism uses A HREF method, to which I want to add more data via form, or otherwise, to be read by the receiving page.

In HTML source below, observe:

- I have a link to portal.php, which includes query parameters
- clicking that link engages the `modal_box` mechanism
- my link is a button

I need to have a way to add data (`GET`, or `POST`), that will submit upon the click of that button, and be received by the resulting page (portal.php in my example).

I want, for example, to be able to print on my receiving page that the following are true:

```
$_GET['p'] == 'select';
$_GET['coverpage'] == 'standard';
```

How?

**Snippet Follows:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>T</title>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".modal_box").click(function() {
        $("#iframe_dialog_box").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));
        $("#div_modal_box").dialog({
          width: 300,
          height: 200,
          modal: true,
          close: function() {
            $("#iframe_dialog_box").attr('src', "about:blank");
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="div_modal_box" title="portal.php?p=select" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="iframe_dialog_box" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </div>
  <form METHOD="GET">
    <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="standard" checked="checked">standard
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="more">more
    <br>



    <a href="portal.php?p=select&amp;action=print" class="modal_box">
      <button type="submit">Generate</button>
    </a>
    <script>
      $("button").button();
    </script>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use a link to submit. Use normal form submission, and put the extra parameters in hidden inputs.

Comment: that will work but then I will need to find a way to submit to the modal box, while staying on the same page.  My workflow is like this ... click "Generate" -> open up modal box, which generates a JS graph, which then redirects user to a new page that uses the graph in a PDF.  This is done so that when user clicks browser's Back button from PDF, the user is returned to the original page and not the page with the JS graph.  If I can use FORM to submit data to the modal box, I will be all set.  But I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Submitting a form with `METHOD=GET` is just like clicking on a link. They both send a `GET` request and reload the page with the reply.

Comment: Could you write custom onClick() to your button, which would set href string of enclosing link adding coverpage param?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the trick you're playing with the `href` and the `iframe`. I'll have to think about this a bit.

Comment: Yes..  Using `method="GET"` works, but bypasses my iframe.  Empty iframe does show up for a moment when I use this method, but then browser redirects me to the to full page where my temporary JS graph is generated...  Originally, before I used the iframe, users who were clicking back from final resting page were going back to the temporary JS page (which redirected them right back to the final (receiving) page.  Hence the iframe, to keep temporary stuff in the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler should get the values from the form, and add them to the URL before assigning the iframe src:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").button();
  $(".modal_box").click(function() {
    var coverpage = $(":radio[name=coverpage]").val();
    $("#iframe_dialog_box").attr('src', $(this).attr("href") + '&coverpage=' + coverpage);
    $("#div_modal_box").dialog({
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      modal: true,
      close: function() {
        $("#iframe_dialog_box").attr('src', "about:blank");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="div_modal_box" title="portal.php?p=select" style="display:none;">
  <iframe id="iframe_dialog_box" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<form METHOD="GET">
  <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="standard" checked="checked">standard
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="more">more
  <br>
  <a href="portal.php?p=select&amp;action=print" class="modal_box">
    <button type="submit">Generate</button>
  </a>
</form>
```

Comment: oh wow.. that is so simple and yet so devilishly clever .  Thanks Barmar!